# Assembly hashcode does not change between two releases

Tags: model-view-controller, assemblies, .net-assembly, hashcode

I override `Application_BeginRequest` and add assembly version to javascript filenames. That way I am sure that after every release, browsers do not get cached javascript. That was working pretty fine upon today: I got the same assembly hashcode event though I made changes in assembly class files and had a couple of builds between those two releases. In my mind, it is almost impossible to have the same assembly hash code in two relases. Am I overseeing anything?

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string origionalPath = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

        if (origionalPath.StartsWith("/Scripts") == true
              && Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension == ".js")
        {
            string fileName = Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1];

            int assemblyHashcode = typeof(KVpro.MyApplication.MvcApplication).Assembly.GetHashCode();

            string fileNameRewrite = fileName.Replace(string.Format(".{0}", assemblyHashcode), string.Empty);

            string rewritePath = origionalPath.Replace(fileName, fileNameRewrite);

            Context.RewritePath(rewritePath);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? try the new bundling and minification of MVC4 to add the real hash of the JavaScript and css files to your final combined scripts and css files URLs. Now it doesn't matter your .dll files are changed or not.

Comment: Well we're still on MVC3 and we can't currently convert our project...

Comment: MVC4 is compatible with MVC3 and it runs on windows 2003 too. (it's not based on the .NET 4.5 which is not compatible with earlier versions of the windows) you can find a conversion guide here: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806